# File separator Java. Is it determimed at compile or runtime?

Tags: java, linux, windows, path

I have the task to convert a code, written to be run under Windows, to also run under Linux.

The first issue I am trying to fix is that the File.separator is not used. Instead there are bunch of hardcoded Srings using  the windows file separator `\` .

I am running the java code under Linux environment via VirtualMachine, which is bit slow.

In order to make my life easier I just compiled my code ( it takes about 1h to compile the entire code) under Windows, and pasted the class files into the Linux Environment.

So my question is, does File.separator get determined at runtime or compile time, because I am still facing the same issues with paths?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/File.java#File.0separator

Comment: The place where path separator comes from is File System, which is abstract. Does that mean the concrete instance will be returned only at run time, therefore meaning it will return the correct path separator at Runtime ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is determined at runtime.

In [the OpenJDK 8 implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/File.java#File.0separator), the `File#separator` will be initialized through the the `FileSystem` returned through `DefaultFileSystem#getFileSystem()`. This class will be provided by the JRE. It will give you a different value depending on a Windows or Linux installation.

In [the OpenJDK 7 implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/File.java#File.0separator), a `FileSystem` implementation was returned through a `native` call. The value returned again depended on the local environment.